# Writing file line by line in C# very slow using streamreader/streamwriter

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I wrote a Winform application that reads in each line of a text file, does a search and replace using RegEx on the line, and then it writes back out to a new file. I chose the "line by line" method as some of the files are just too large to load into memory.

I am using the BackgroundWorker object so the UI can be updated with the progress of the job. Below is the code (with parts omitted for brevity) that handles the reading and then outputting of the lines in the file.

```
public void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Details of obtaining file paths omitted for brevity

    int totalLineCount = File.ReadLines(inputFilePath).Count();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputFilePath))
    {
      int currentLine = 0;
      String line;
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        currentLine++;

        // Match and replace contents of the line
        // omitted for brevity

        if (currentLine % 100 == 0)
        {
          int percentComplete = (currentLine * 100 / totalLineCount);
          bgWorker.ReportProgress(percentComplete);
        }

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
          sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Some of the files I am processing are very large (8 GB with 132 million rows). The process takes a very long time (a 2 GB file took about 9 hours to complete). It looks to be working at around 58 KB/sec. Is this expected or should the process be going faster?

Comment: doesn't `StreamWriter` write the file from the start when you append a line? Could explain why it's taking so long if for every 132 million lines its starting over. So it would be 132! (factorial) operations

Comment: You can write a file line by line without reopening it and seeking to the end for EVERY SINGLE LINE, you know... Just open the output file once at the start of the loop.

Comment: The determination to wait 9 hours until the application completes before re-thinking your current process lol

Comment: By the way, depending on the version of Visual Studio you have, you can use the Profiler to identify bottlenecks https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: @user1 Yes, if you are appending a line to an existing file, rather than rewriting, you end up with a couple of forms of overhead. 1) instantiation of the object 2) reading to find the end pointer, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't close and re-open the writing file every loop iteration, just open the writer outside the file loop. This should improve performance as the writer no longer needs to seek to the end of the file every single loop iteration.

Also`File.ReadLines(inputFilePath).Count();`  is causing you to read your input file twice and could be a big chunk of time. Instead of a percentage based off of lines calculate the percentage based off of stream position.

```
public void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Details of obtaining file paths omitted for brevity

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath, true)) //You can use this constructor instead of FileStream, it does the same operation.
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputFilePath))
    {
      int lastPercentage = 0;
      String line;
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {

        // Match and replace contents of the line
        // omitted for brevity

        //Poisition and length are longs not ints so we need to cast at the end.
        int currentPercentage = (int)(sr.BaseStream.Position * 100L / sr.BaseStream.Length);
        if (lastPercentage != currentPercentage )
        {
          bgWorker.ReportProgress(currentPercentage );
          lastPercentage = currentPercentage;
        }
          sw.WriteLine(line);
      }
    }
}
```

Other than that you will need to show what `Match and replace contents of the line omitted for brevity` does as I would guess that is where your slowness comes from. Run a profiler on your code and see where it is taking the most time and focus your efforts there.

Comment: I'd also use [`File.ReadLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) along with `foreach` to go through the input file. Not faster, but more readable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you could not get a total count with that without reading through the file twice, however I updated my answer with a workaround to that using the stream position instead of lines.

Comment: Awesome! This worked great! The speed has improved by a HUGE amount. Thanks also for the suggestion to calculate the percentage complete also. I will just modify to only report the progress on ever 100th iteration so the UI does not update on every loop.

Comment: @webworm Updating every 100'th iteration is likely part of your problem too, you are flooding the UI with updates. Since you know what you are sending the UI, and what you sent last time, only report back to the UI when the last value is different than the current value. With this method you have at max 100 UI updates, with your method you could have 1000's or 10,000's of updates all telling the UI to re-use the same number you told it to use last time you reported.

Comment: @Scott - I see ... so you are already taken care of that by only sending out  the update when the percentage is different. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Follow this process:

1. Instantiate reader and writer
2. Loop through lines, doing the next two steps
3. In loop change line
4. In loop write changed line
5. Dispose of reader and writer

This should be a LOT faster than instantiating the writer on each line loop, as you have.

I will append this with a code sample shortly. Looks like someone else beat me to the punch on code samples - see @Scott Chamberlain's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ReadAllLines method at the top as the reads through whole file just to get numberof lines.

Comment: But I need the number of lines counted so I can determine the percentage done

Comment: Look into Scott Chamberlain's solution, he has solved that problem nicely.